# Is there a similar to bash set ±x directive in php?

Tags: php, bash

`set -x` makes the output more clarified, i.e. you can see ‘under the cover’, values substitution and what is actually done. `set +x` brings the default behavior back.

Comment: To make this question better (for searches, clarification of intent, and casual readers), please explain what aspect(s)/behavior(s) of `set +/-x` are desired.

Comment: Could you be talking about tracing? (as in set -x prints the lines executed)

Comment: I'm sure it's an interesting question, and there's even a chance I might know the answer, but since I don't know what this directive is, I can't really help. Voting -1, but I will revert that if you make the question a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Didn’t buried IE today, Spudley?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a tracing of php execution with the [xdebug extension](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace), that can do variable expansion and various other data collection too.

Comment: I know about xdebug but tracing with it often means line-by-line crouching on the code and I wanted something embeddable that I can use like try…catch construction for the blocks I want to be traced.

Comment: There is `xdebug_start_trace()` and `xdebug_stop_trace()` if you want to surround only a small part for tracing, also maybe for this remote deubgging would be more appropriate (also provided by xdebug)

Comment: The thing is, I used only remote debugging (with GEBEN and Emacs) and didn’t know about these functions.